# Detectar dos teclas pulsadas al mismo tiempo java

Tags: java

estoy desarrollando un juego en java con netbeans para la universidad sobre un personaje que salta para evitar obstáculos.

Cuando detecto una tecla direccional presionada se mueve a la derecha o izquierda respectivamente, y cuando detecto la tecla espacio salta.

Mi problema es el siguiente y es que cuando tengo presionada una tecla direccional se mueve correctamente, pero al momento de saltar deja de moverse a la derecha y solo salta, haciendo que tenga que volver a presionar la tecla para moverme horizontalmente.

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de detectar dos teclas presionadas al mismo tiempo, así cuando salte, el personaje siga moviéndose horizontalmente sin tener que volver a presionar la tecla direccional.

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int code = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
                switch (code) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        clown.run_rigth(7);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        clown.run_left(7);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                        if (!clown.getSalta()) {
                            clown.setSalta(true);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No hay un evento key down? keypressed solo se suele ejecutar al momento de presionar...

Comment: como deberia implementar un evento key down(){